# Could not load NIB in bundle with name: '5JK-D5-ZKP-view-1nz-4p-isc'

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nsbundle

I have a storyboard and it has 2 view controllers including UINavigationController itself. I did some changes in the application and that bug strangely came up.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/***/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96021E81-BD05-4193-86ED-7F386739B99E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E684814B-7F84-41CE-B762-64C66A4AE4F8/***.app> (loaded)' with name '5JK-D5-ZKP-view-1nz-4p-isc''
```

I tried disabling *Size Classes*, did not work. I also dived into exploring the storyboards XML, found out that `5JK-D5-ZKP` is the segue of `root view controller` found in navigation controller, and `1nz-4p-isc` is the table view inside the `UITableViewController`, which is root view controller.

Comment: This could have been a result of other codes. You should consider tell us what changes you did before this happened (in code) or include a sample project.

Comment: I found out the reason, I'm going to write it down now. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem was there was a custom initialization in `UITableViewController` subclass with its method `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. Being no additional initialization method overridden there, that override was roughly resembling this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //  Initialize fetcher
    fetcher = QuestionFetcher(delegate: self)

    //  Call the super.init method
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //  Initialize the activity indicator for fetching questions
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.size.width / 2.00, y: tableView.frame.size.height / 2.00, width: 20, height: 20))
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.hidden = true
}
```

What's tricky there is, the reader of the signature found in the storyboard tries to call `init?(coder: NSCoder)` found in the override, however as you see, it is a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224). But that view controller was not loading from a coder, so it failed.